# SpecFlow/Cucumber - Documenting available steps

Tags: .net, documentation, bdd, specflow

Our company is looking at implementing BDD in our .NET application. Specifically, SpecFlow.

We can foresee a large number of common steps being created ('Given a customer', etc), so what methods have been used to document these, so that the business can reference them? Is XmlDoc on the step definition classes sufficient, or have others found better methods of documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step definition report of SpecFlow provides the information, which steps have been defined, and whether and how often they are actually used, as well as which steps have no step definition yet. You can read more about it on the [Reporting page of the SpecFlow wiki](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Reporting).

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I must have missed that - I knew about the execution report.